# How feasible it may be to get Australian 491 visa in a year?

Tags: working-visas, australia

I am currently 44. My brother who was working in Australia, very recently got PR. He is ready to sponsor me under 491 visa. Skill, education, experience, English are not a problem for me.

What I am wondering is how feasible it may be to convert an EOI to visa because 45 is the age limit for these visas in Australia. Max by Feb 24 I may be able to get the EOI done with all the formalities required, which gives me 6 months before i turn 45.

Comment: According to [Visa processing times](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-processing-times/global-visa-processing-times) a 491 takes up to 29 months. Have you had an [invitation to apply](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/working-in-australia/skillselect/invitation-rounds) yet?

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to the likelihood of getting a visa within a certain time frame but I will note that the age limit is for being invited.

According to the [491 eligibility page](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/skilled-work-regional-provisional-491/application#Eligibility) at the time of writing:

> You must be aged under 45 to be invited to apply for the visa.
>
> You can still apply for the visa if you turn 45 after we invite you to apply.
>
> If you turn 45 after you submit your EOI but before we invite you to
> apply you will not receive an invite.